# Single Laravel OAuth server for multi Laravel projects

Tags: laravel, authentication

There are four Laravel 7 projects, Project A going to use project B some routes. For sure project B needs to check if the request is authenticated or not. So there is a need to have a specific auth server for that handle authentication of all 4 projects.

Any idea or implementation of this pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very opinion based question, but what you're describing is similar to a microservice or distributed architecture for your projects.

If you need the ability to have one login or one point to authorise all of these projects, then one OAuth service sounds like the right way to go.

I am currently working across 12+ projects at the moment that are all interconnected, Laravel based, microservices. 
We use one Laravel OAuth service to handle logins across all of the projects.

To login to Project A, you are directed to the Login service to login and redirected back.
For API or machine-to-machine communication, we still use the Login service. To do so, we setup a personal access client inside the Login service and then create user accounts for the projects. We then generate a personal access token for each project.
When Project A makes an API request to Project B, Project B takes the authentication token and verifies it is valid against the Login service by calling an api/user endpoint.

If they don't all need one single login, then you may be able to get away without one and just generate local API tokens that consuming projects need to use to authenticate against that project.

Comment: Thank you James, I am waiting for more answer, let's see what others think about.

Comment: To solve this issue, I changed the authentication to JWT. If all the projects has the same JTW secret, the host project (project B) can authenticate the request which is coming from project A. 

Pay attention the all project should have the same JWT auth gourd in `config/auth.php`.

Hope it helps you all.

Comment: You’re free to do whatever works for you @HamidAfghan. Although sharing secrets for convenience, is poor practice in my opinion. Glad you got it working in the end!

Comment: After 1 year and more I totally agree. It is a poor practice and it is not recommendend. Thanks